# validar un dato de BD y mostrar resulatados en un option

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

El detalle que tengo es que ocupo validar un texto(RFC) de un input, y que cuando se de click en un submit comprobar me regrese los clientes con el mismo RFC en un option.... ya busque y no entiendo como hacerlo...

esta parte es la de la busqueda con la consulta SQL

```
<label> 
      <select id="cbx_nombre" name="cbx_nombre">
                    <?php

                    include "conexion.php";
                    $consult = "SELECT *from usuarios3 where RFC = 'RFC123' "; /*AQUI VA EL RFC*/
                    $ejecutar=mysqli_query($conexion, $consult) or die (mysqli_error($conexion));
                    ?>
                    <option>Selecciona::</option>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($ejecutar as $opciones):?>

                        <option value="<?php echo $opciones['id_cliente'] ?>">
                            <?php echo $opciones['id_cliente'] ?>
                </option>

                    <?php endforeach ?>


            </select>
        </label>
```

se que con jquery, pero no entiendo bien al 100 como podria hacer eso...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

      var consulta;

      //hacemos focus
      $("#usuario").focus();

      //comprobamos si se pulsa una tecla
      $("#usuario").click(function(e){
             //obtenemos el texto introducido en el campo
             consulta = $("#usuario").val();

             //hace la búsqueda
             $("#resultado").delay(1000).queue(function(n) {      

                  $("#resultado").html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />');

                        $.ajax({
                              type: "POST",
                              url: "comprobar.php",
                              data: "b="+consulta,
                              dataType: "html",
                              error: function(){
                                    alert("error petición ajax");
                              },
                              success: function(data){                                                      
                                    $("#resultado").html(data);
                                    n();
                              }
                  });

             });

      });

});
    </script>
```

Comment: no me termina de quedar clara tu duda, tratas de validar para evitar que se ingrese 2 veces el mismo RFC?

Comment: es que no se como explicarlo.... quiero que al consultar RFC me traiga los clientes que tienen ese mismo RFC

Comment: Creo que tu código tiene muchos errores, a simple vista, por ejemplo tu consulta tiene un error, necesitas separar el `*` del `from`, después en el código JQuery, el evento para cuando se presiona una tecla son: `keypress`, `keyup`, `keydown`, y que es la funcion `n()`?

Comment: la funncion n pretendia que es la que muestra los resultados en el div...., pero entonces nada que ver lo que intento?, me podrian ayudar a acomodarlo... neta ya busque en google, "como comprobar el texto de un input", "como pasar texto de un input a un select", "get value input and pass to select"